# What are the triangles around Kermit's neck?

Tags: character, muppets

What is the ring of triangles around Kermit's neck?

Looking at pictures of frogs, I have been unable to find one that has similar markings. For example, take this picture of a typical frog:

[image]

Kermit, of course, has a signature ring of triangles around his neck:

[image]

So far I have been unable to find any credible evidence of *what* that ring is. No interviews with Jim Henson, for example.

One reason given is that ring hides a seam between the puppet's head and body: while this gives a *why* it is there, especially for a puppet built in the 1950s without modern technology, it does not explain *what* it is. Another is that Kermit started out as a lizard or nameless animal and later turned into a frog: however, would his appearance not be updated to match his species? Again, this theory does not explain *what* it is.

This thread on Reddit touches on the various theories and is a good, concise overview: however, it offers no *credible evidence* to back up any of the claims of *what* that ring is.

[Why does Kermit the Frog have a ring of pointy flaps around his neck?](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/2igite/why_does_kermit_the_frog_have_a_ring_of_pointy/)

Note: if you follow the Wikipedia links for Kermit there are some articles that assert he was species-less at first with Henson quotes to back it up: however, upon becoming a frog I would expect his features to match that of a frog as close as one could expect a fictional anthropomorphized muppet to match. His original species is largely irrelevant to his *frog* features.

Comment: I want to be very clear here: the title is **what** is around his neck, not **why** is it there (i.e. to hide the seam in the puppet).

Comment: It always looked like a jester's collar to me.

Comment: http://www.henson.com/jimsredbook/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Tinkerdee-slide-Kermit.jpg

Comment: It appears to be an actual collar, rather than part of his person; http://www.henson.com/jimsredbook/2014/08/8201975/

Comment: Why would you expect a Muppet frog to "*match [the features] of a frog as close as one could expect*"... I suppose you expect to see pigs with luxurious golden hair and hats on bears? Most Muppets have clothes... So does Kermie.

Comment: @Catija well, last year they discovered a frog that looks exactly like kermit, sans collar http://i.stack.imgur.com/INYK4.jpg

Comment: @Catija I would expect that to make it easy for a child to identify a character as belonging to a particular species or genus. Miss Piggy has a snout and pig ears, for example, despite her other features, making her easily identifiable as a pig. Kermit is basically... green. I guess the lack of ears helps (frogs just have tympanic membranes). When I think of a frog I think of a small aquatic creature that hops around and sticks his tongue out to eat flies. Kermit neither hops nor sticks his tongue out, adding to the mystery.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a... Collar. Like a *Prince's* or Jester's collar. It has nothing to do with being a frog actually, aside that it somehow made him look more frog like. Likely because it gives a nice separation between head and body. Otherwise he just looks like a lizard. Which he used to be.

[image][image]

But to Kermit, it's just a piece of clothes. [From the Muppet's Wikia for the Collar.](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Kermit_the_Frog%27s_collar)

> ***It's a Very Merry Muppet Christmas Movie*** cuts in to the end of an interview with Kermit on Last Call with Carson Daly with the frog saying **"...and that's why I have this funny collar!"**
>
> In ***The Muppets*** episode "*The Ex-Factor,*" Piggy tells Kermit he should get a plastic surgeon to tighten up his neck waddle stating **"Your pointy jester collar ain't hiding anything."**

From another episode, *"Crystal Gayle"*, he says he feels naked when it gets stolen:
[image]

Further more:

> With the exception of Constantine and various other Kermit impersonators, no other Muppet Frogs sport a pointed collar like Kermit.

From ***"The Frog Prince"*** were Kermit first wore his iconic pointed collar. Notice all the other frogs are collar-less. Kermit is the only non-nudist in a nudist colony of frogs it seems:
[image]

From it's *Royal* origins of a Frog Prince, it's more like Shakespeare's collar than anything else.

[image]

Personally, it inspires images of a lily pad or water lily.

[image]

Comment: The image from episode 402 [here](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Naked_Muppets) might be useful. Episode guide [here](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_402:_Crystal_Gayle).

Comment: Personally, it evokes an image of a lily pad which frogs will sit on. Perhaps that is why it makes him look frog-like despite no real frog having such a thing?

Comment: I think the key piece of evidence here is that it can be "stolen," implying it is not physically part of his body. That provides a _very_ strong argument for your assertion that it is simply a collar. Assuming nobody posts another answer with equal or stronger evidence to back it up, I will accept this answer in a day or two.

Comment: @Snowman Not sure whether that's a good indication since it is also possible to steal the nose of little kids although being a physically part of their body.